# Initializing private instance variables, does using shorthand syntax introduces bad practices or odd behavior?

Tags: flutter, dart, class, syntax, constructor

For example:

Would changing this

```dart
abstract class MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  MultiChildLayoutDelegate({ Listenable? relayout }) : _relayout = relayout;

  final Listenable? _relayout;
  ...
```

to this

```dart
abstract class MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  MultiChildLayoutDelegate({ this._relayout });

  final Listenable? _relayout;
  ...
```

create an unexpected behavior, or is it a bad practice, or is it OK?

I am not asking for this class in particular, but for any custom class on my code base.

I haven't noticed anything strange, but I would like to be sure.

Comment: Ok, & feels better `({ this._relayout });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving a *named* parameter a name with a leading underscore is objectively not okay.  It's not allowed.  You should be getting a [`private_optional_parameter`](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#private_optional_parameter) analysis error. (Note that despite the name of the error, it's about *named* parameters, not *optional* parameters.  Presumably the misnomer is historical and hasn't been corrected for compatibility reasons.)

Dart for the Web generates a compilation error when compiling to JavaScript.

The Dart VM generates compile-time errors for optional named parameters (but currently [is inconsistent for `required` named parameters](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/51472)).

Even if it were allowed, giving a named parameter a name with a leading underscore would place a small but additional burden on callers, who then would need to use the underscore in the parameter name.  That subjectively would be ugly and awkward.

Comment: @OppositeDragon Have you run `dart analyze` on your code?

Comment: Also see https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b4a2843ee665688e16078b75a74fd668, and try copying-and-pasting that code into a `.dart` file and running it with `dart your_file.dart`.

Comment: You are right, I do get the mentioned error. Thanks for pointing that out.